# mb_substr cant be used on PHP 5.2.6

Tags: php, function

Fatal error:

> Call to undefined function mb_substr()

After moving to my dedicated server (hypervm CP), I got lots of errors.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the [mbstring](http://php.net/mbstring) extension, which provides that kind of functions, is not installed or enabled : if it was enabled, you'd have a block "mbstring", in the output of `phpinfo()`.

If you are admin of your server, a first idea might be to check for something like

```
extension=mbstring
```

In you `php.ini` file.

Comment: heu... no idea about that, sorry ; typically, it's in `/etc/`, like `/etc/php.ini` or `/etc/php5/apache/php.ini` or so -- but no idea about that "control panel".